# How do I wait for the same event to occur?

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to record audio, and I don't want to simply use the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)` function because I want to control the recording myself. Here's what I have..

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
        using (WasapiCapture capture = new CSCore.SoundIn.WasapiLoopbackCapture())
        {
            //initialize the selected device for recording
            capture.Initialize();

            //... stuff...

            //create a wavewriter to write the data to
            using (WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter(@directory, capture.WaveFormat))
            {
                capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //save the recorded audio
                    w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
                };

                //start recording
                capture.Start();

                //wait until button is pressed again...

                //stop recording
                capture.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to make it so that when I click `buttonStart` again, the `capture.Stop();` line will run. I'm pretty new to C#, so I just wanted to ask.

Comment: Your capture variable would have to be declared outside of that scope.  If capture isn't null, you stop it, if it is null, you start it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WasapiCapture capture;

 private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
       if(capture == null)
                capture = new new CSCore.SoundIn.WasapiLoopbackCapture();
                capture.Initialize();
                capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //save the recorded audio
                    using (WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter(@directory, capture.WaveFormat))
                    {
                        w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
                    }
                };

                //start recording
                capture.Start();
            }
        else {   
                //stop recording
                capture.Stop();
                capture = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To let some *code* *wait until...* you can use threads. And once of best ways of implementing a *wait until some event occurs* is using an `AutoResetEvent`:

```
public class Program
{
    // AutoResetEvent constructor argument is if the event should be start
    // signaled or not.
    //
    // A ResetEvent is like a door. If it's signaled, the door is open,
    // and if it's not signaled, the door is closed.
    private static readonly AutoResetEvent ResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run
        (
            () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                // Calling Set() is signaling the event. That is, 
                // you open the door. And other threads waiting until
                // the door is opened get resumed.
                ResetEvent.Set();
            }
        );

        // Since the ResetEvent isn't signaled, the door is closed
        // and it'll wait until the door gets opened (i.e. the event
        // gets signaled).
        ResetEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("This will be written once the ResetEvent has been signaled in the other thread");
    }
}
```

Now you can apply this approach to yours and you'll get exactly what you are asking for.